# How to use typescript keyof for multiple interface in a function

Tags: typescript

I have these interfaces and I would like to use onErrorType in different places in one place name is key of INewCustomerForm in another place key of IExistingCustomerForm

```
export interface INewCustomerForm {
id?: string;
site: string;
isRegisteredGst: false;
businessName: string;
abn: string;
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
email: string;
phone: string;
address: string;
postcode: string;
suburb: string;
state: string;
siteAddress: string;
sitePostcode: string;
siteSuburb: string;
siteState: string;
}

export interface IExistingCustomerForm {
  id: string;
  email: string;
}

export type onErrorType = (
  name: keyof INewCustomerForm | keyof IExistingCustomerForm
) => boolean | undefined;
```

in one file I have

```
     const handleError: onErrorType = (
        name: keyof IExistingCustomerForm
      ) => (errors[name] && touched[name] ? true : false);
```

in another place I have

```
     const handleError: onErrorType = (name: keyof 
      INewCustomerForm) => errors[name] && touched[name] ? true : false;
```

I am getting error:
Type '(name: keyof IExistingCustomerForm) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'onErrorType'.
Types of parameters 'name' and 'name' are incompatible.
Type '"id" | "site" | "isRegisteredGst" | "businessName" | "abn" | "firstName" | "lastName" | "email" | "phone" | "address" | "postcode" | "suburb" | "state" | "siteAddress" | "sitePostcode" | "siteSuburb" | "siteState"' is not assignable to type '"id" | "email"'.
Type '"site"' is not assignable to type '"id" | "email"'

Comment: How didn't work? [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDkIHcDCBXAZzAHsBbaAMWKlOQG8AoZZ5OALmSKlAHMBuBgF8GoSLEQpUAUQAewIr3xEylarUYtkCDl14DhDMAE8ADimIgpUKNQAqplAF5kACibIQcchwDWEI8QwaJi4hCTkUFQ0AD5+AUHScgogPErhqjQMAJTIjgB8yABGxMQANhBwIMjRyHggACYQMKAQ9QIMCBZEyCgcFlY2UPZmuR5eTgV1jc0gre0QLgDkCItZAguLcKvzS4XbQA) seems to work for me

Comment: Please share `errors` variable and `touched`

Comment: const initialValues: IExistingCustomerForm = {
    id: "",
    email: "",
  };

Comment: const initialValues: INewCustomerForm = {
    site: "",
    isRegisteredGst: false,
    businessName: "",
    abn: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    address: "",
    postcode: "",
    suburb: "",
    state: "",
    siteAddress: "",
    sitePostcode: "",
    siteSuburb: "",
    siteState: "",
  };